# Why the object input in the function does not match but still work?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0) : m_n(n)
    {
        std::cout << 'd';
    }
    A(const A& a) : m_n(a.m_n)
    {
        std::cout << 'c';
    }
private:
    int m_n;
};

void f(const A& a1, const A& a2 = A())
{}

int main()
{
    f(3);
}
```

Can any body help to explain the following

```
void f(const A &a1, const A &a2 = A())
{}
```

especially const `A &a2 = A()`.

and why `f(3)`? Why the integer input still work? Should it be object

Answer (score 3):

Because as the parameter is passed it is implicitly converted into an `A`. If you type `explicit` after the integer ctor parameter list, it won't do it anymore.

Comment: Addendum: Rule-of-thumb: Unless you are really sure, make one-argument-ctors `explicit`. Consider default-arguments there too.

Comment: expanding on this: `f(3);` is the same as `f( A(3) );` , the compiler will try to do this for each constructor (and in fact the same thing happens for function calls in general, not just constructor calls)

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh really? I actually love the implicit conversion. Maybe for primitive types it's a good practice to mark explicit (I don't want to accidentally pass an array when I construct with an int, for example), but for everything else I let it stay implicit.

Comment: Only leave it implicit if you are *really sure* it cannot be a bad conversion, so not discarding any info.

Answer (score 1):

> Can any body help to explain the following

```
void f(const A &a1, const A &a2 = A()) {}
```

The expression const `A&a1`, means *const reference to a object type A*

the expression const `A &a2 = A()`, means *const reference to a object type A, if paramenter not provided create new A object*.

using a const reference you tell to compiler, *do not copy my object just pass a reference to it* this is less expensive that using `void f(A a1, A a2 = A()) {}`. in that case the compiler will use the copy constructor 'A(const A& a)'.

> and why f(3)? Why the integer input still work? Should it be object

This is due constructor `A(int n = 0)`, the compiler understand that you want to create a new object type A object, using this constructor and parametrized with value 3.

Answer (score 1):

You have your call:

```
f(3);
```

The function `f` has a defaulted parameter, which it will use if no argument is passed for the second parameter. So the call you're actually making is:

```
f(3, A());
```

The compiler will perform implicit conversion on the first argument unless you use the keyword `explicit` after your constructors. So now your call looks like this:

```
f(A(3), A());
```

Because you have user created constructors you won't get an automatically generated default constructor for `A`, but `A(int n = 0)` has a defaulted parameter, and since no argument was passed, `0` will be used as the argument. So your final call is:

```
f(A(3), A(0));
```

These two objects constructed `A` objects will exist for the lifetime of the `f` function and be treated as `const` objects because the function definition declares it's arguments as `const`.